# failed to load RSL textLayout

Tags: eclipse, signature, fdt, rsls

I just installed gentoo linux amd64.

on that I installed eclipse 4.2M5 with FD5 for flex development.

after compiling my project, when I execute it i get the following in the log file:

```
Error #2046: The loaded file did not have a valid signature.
Failed to load RSL http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/1.1.0.604/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz
Failing over to RSL textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz
Error #2046: The loaded file did not have a valid signature.
```

i use FD5 with Flex 4.1A.

any ideas why it happens ?

update:

it seems that when I close and open my project I am able to execute my project once. the 2nd time that I execute the project on my browser I get the error and I need to close and reopen the browser to execute it again.

Comment: Could it be either a x-domain security issue or you need to run your project through apache (i.e compile your project and open it in a browser via a localhost)?

Comment: hi.. already running from apache

Comment: Are you able to run the project in another IDE. E.g. Flash Builder, Intellij or Flashdevelop?

Comment: i used to run this project in eclipse fdt on OSX Lion, I moved to linux that's all. still using same applications.

Comment: Opening and closing the project doesn't effect compiling. It will just build FDT's internal model, no files will be overwritten or created.  The only thing I can think of would be browser caching. What about trying Chrome while incognito mode (no caching between sessions)

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you for all of your comments.
I finally was able to properly resolve the issue.

it seems that flash saves cache info at ~/.macromedia

(~ for home dir, for example if the user is ufk so it translates to /homeukf)

all I need to do is to delete that folder, since then I am able to refresh my app on the browser without any problems.